# How do I bandpass-filter a signal using a Gaussian function in Python (Numpy/Scipy)

Tags: numpy, filter, scipy, gaussian

I have a time series (more specifically a correlation function). I want to bandpass-filter this signal using a Gaussian function H:

```
H(w) = e^(-alpha((w-wn)/wn)^2),
```

where wn is the central frequency in my bandpass filter and alpha is a certain constant value that I know.
I apply a (inverse) FFT to my H function:

```
H = np.e ** (-alfa * ((w - wn) / wn) ** 2)
H = np.fft.ifft(H)
HH = np.asarray([i1 for i1 in itertools.chain(H[len(H)/2:len(H)], H[0:len(H)/2])])
```

And what I do then is to use fftconvolve:

```
filtered = fftconvolve(data, HH.real, mode='same'),
```

but the "filtered signal" that I see seems to be filtering frequencies centered in 2 times wn.

What is the correct way of doing this? Is there a restriction in the length of my filter with respect to the length of my time series?

Comment: Just some comments: `ifft` is *inverse* fourier transform, not sure if that matters here.  Also, use `H = np.exp(...)` instead of `np.e**(...)`.  Finally, use `HH = np.fft.fftshift(H)` instead of the `itertools` contraption.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is the Gaussian filter from Scipy,

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter

output = gaussian_filter(input, sigma )
```

where sigma is the standard deviation of the Gaussian kernel.  See the Scipy documentation for more details.   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html